# Overwriting object in google cloud storage failed

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I try to upload a new version of a file to the bucket.

```
gsutil cp test.txt gs://mybucket/test.txt
```

and receive a 403 response:

```
Copying "direction: ltr;" class="">AccessDeniedException: 403 xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.delete access to mybucket/test.txt.
```

Actually, the service account has an Object Creator role.
Is it not enough?

Comment: Does your bucket have Fine-grained or uniform access? and where did you asigned the role for that service accoun in the IAM console or in the ACL's?

Answer (score 3):

According to the official documentation

> Storage Object Creator
>
> > Allows users to create objects. Does not give permission to view,
> >     delete, or overwrite objects
>
> resourcemanager.projects.get
>
> resourcemanager.projects.list
>
> storage.objects.create

Therefore, please assign to your service account `Storage Object Admin (roles/storage.objectAdmin)` because you do not have `storage.objects.delete` access to the bucket used in versioning process.
When you upload a new version of your file to your Cloud Storage bucket, Object Versioning moves the existing object into a noncurrent state.

I reproduced your use case with a service account that have `Object Creator role` on a bucket that has `Access control Uniform` and versioning enabled and got the same error message:

`service-account.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.delete access to your-bucket/file`

Comment: Storage Object Admin is too much in my case. I don't want to allow the service account to perform any admin action. For example, define the bucket public.

Comment: I think you make a confusion between `Storage Object Admin (roles/storage.objectAdmin)` and `Storage Admin (roles/storage.admin)` [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles). You can also create a custom role by adding `storage.objects.delete` to permissions of the `Storage Object Creator`.

Comment: For future reference: `roles/storage.objectUser` might be what you're looking for.

See: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles